# Async with Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, multiprocessing

Ok, so I have 2 different programs, both async. I need to share data from one of them to the other, I've tried with multiprocessing but it didn't work with async (idk if I did it right or not).

I have no more ideas of what to do. (Comment if I'm not explaining my self correctly)
The idea is to pass data from one async process to the other, I don't really want to use TXT.

Comment: Are both/either attempting to update this shared state?

Answer (score 0):

What type of data do you need to share?. If it is something like dictionary, you can use Redis.
https://github.com/redis/redis-py

You will need redis server installed and running.

process one:

```py
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r.set('foo', 'bar')
```

process 2:

```py
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r.get('foo')
```

Comment: I don't really know what type of data it is, but I assume it will be something like huge array.
I've seen that option, I'm not sure if it's useful in my case, but i appreciate the response.

Comment: You can store array in redis. If data is not bigger than 512 MB it should work.